# Showing three admob ads in TabView

Tags: android, admob

I need to show one banner ad per one tabview, so I changes the android:id  (check below code) and the add is successfully appears in all required tabs. Is it ok or its against Google's Terms of Service. Please tell me if any other way to show the ads

XML

First Layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="@string/admobid"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
```

Second

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView2"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="@string/admobid"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
```

Third one

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView3"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="@string/admobid"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
```

Java code:

```
adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("356d67mydeviceid")

     .build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);

     adView2 = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
     AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("356d67mydeviceid")

     .build();
     adView2.loadAd(adRequest2);

     adView3 = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView3);
     AdRequest adRequest3 = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("356d67mydeviceid")
     .build();
     adView3.loadAd(adRequest3);
Output
```

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-CPKhDMkAwnU/U5_PtY4U_vI/AAAAAAAAADc/tUeQZTwnBdo/s320/tabview.png

Answer (score 0):

While perhaps not against the spirit of the Admob policy it is probably technically agsint the letter of it. You are probably better off creating a single AdView and positioning it above or below your TabView.

Answer (score 0):

Place your tabview and ad banner into the same layout